# Calling ClearCanvas exe with arguments from c# windows application

Tags: c#, clearcanvas

I am trying to call the ClearCanvas exe with aruments from Windows application using C#, but I am not able to call it. Below is my code..

string[] args = new string[2];
            args[0] = "ClearCanvas.Desktop";

```
        Process pro = new Process();

        pro.StartInfo.FileName = @"D:\ClearCanvasWorkStation\Desktop\Executable\bin\Debug\ClearCanvas.Desktop.Executable.exe";
        pro.StartInfo.Arguments = args[0];

        pro.Start();
```

What am I supposed to send as an argument and what I need to do if I want to send more than one argument?

Comment: BTW, "am not able to call it" is not very detailed explanation what did not work - i.e. it missing expected behavior and possible error messages.

Answer (score 0):

[Arguments](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.diagnostics.processstartinfo.arguments.aspx) is a string that contains command line arguments as if you typed them in command line.

```
 Process process = new Process();
 process.StartInfo.FileName = 
    @"D:\Cle...Debug\ClearCanvas.Desktop.Executable.exe";
 process.StartInfo.Arguments = "paramet1 parameter2 \"param with space\" parameter4";
 process.Start();
```

Since it is your custom application I don't know what your application expects...